# Oracle ORA-02089 with Java

Tags: java, plsql, oracle11g

I'm getting the following error when trying to call a PL/SQL stored procedure from Java: `ORA-02089: COMMIT is not allowed in a subordinate session`

It tests fine from Oracle. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Are you using the XA libs?  http://ora-02089.ora-code.com/  Similar thread: https://community.jboss.org/message/515056?_sscc=t

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this ways;

- Change the data source to use Non-XA (and check  the “Supports Global
  Transactions” & “Emulate Two-Phase Commit” buttons)
- Delete the COMMIT from your code.
- Use the “PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION“. This will kind of create a
  separate transaction that will allow to use a commit.For
  example:CREATE PROCEDURE XXX AS PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; BEGIN
  …

Comment: changing datasource from XA to connection pool worked for me

Answer (score 4):

What does the oracle documentation say about the error:

> COMMIT was issued in a session that is not the two-phase commit global
>   coordinator.

Basically you are executing a distributed transaction. As part of a distributed transaction you are trying to invoke an autonomous transaction. This is not possible as distributed transactions are required to do a 2PC.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I think it's related to XA. It works fine when I bracket the stored procedure with [AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION Pragma](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems002.htm):

```
PROCEDURE foo (val IN VARCHAR2(4000)) is
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES (val);
  DELETE FROM tbl2;
  COMMIT;
END foo;
```